# Angular making a service accessable from everywhere

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have service that i am using to check if my users are allowed to see the content in my application.

i use it like this:

```
<tab ng-controller="LibraryRTLController" ng-if="authFactory.hasFeature('ReadyToLearn')">
```

However it doesnt seem to work properly because i would have to intialize it in every controller which seems redundant.

So my question is: is there someway that i can use a service globaly?

Please note that for reasons i can't begin to explain here i have to use `ng-if` so an attribute directive will not help me!

**Update**

So ive added it to my run function:

```
angular.module('app')
.run(function ($rootScope, AuthService, authFactory, $state) {
    $rootScope.authFactory = authFactory;
    $rootScope.$on('$stateChangeStart', function (event, next, toParams) {
        $state.newState = next;
        var authorizedRoles = next.data.authorizedRoles;
        if (!AuthService.isAuthorized(authorizedRoles)) {
            event.preventDefault();
            if (AuthService.isAuthenticated()) {
                // user is not allowed
            } else {
                // user is not logged in
                window.location.href = "http://" + window.location.hostname
            }
        }
    });
})
```

When debugging i am able to see that it is actually setting the variable correctly.

in my service ive created a function that simply just alerts:

```
function doesWork ()
{
    alert('true!');
}
```

Now back in my html i have:

```
<tab ng-controller="LibraryRTLController" ng-init="authFactory.doesWork()">
```

However without any results?

Comment: You can crete custom directive that will have injected your auth service and will simply remove element if user doesn't have rights to see current element

Comment: @ArturGórski Yep however i need to use ng-if

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> is there someway that i can use a service globally?

You can simply expose service as the `$rootScope` property so it will be available in every template:

```
appModule.run(['$rootScope', 'authFactory', function($rootScope, authFactory) {
  $rootScope.authFactory = authFactory;
}]);
```

Comment: What if the service is in another module? will that work? because right now it does not seem to work :(

Comment: Yes, $rootScope is common for all modules in your app. It should definitely work. Can you replicate a demo maybe? However, "another modules" is part of the main application module, right?

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can access service globally by referring the service name in main root file where you inject dependency

```
appModule.run(['$rootScope', 'authFactory', function($rootScope, authFactory) {
  $rootScope.authFactory = authFactory;
}]);
```

Comment: @dfsq you did a write code and same thing is what i am saying in my answer i just give reference